# Streaming audio/video in a publicly-hosted server increases bandwith usage

Tags: linux, bandwidth, streaming, video-streaming

I have a website hosted in a public server (withoud any streaming content) ,using public hosting instead of private because its cheaper. But in public hosting their are limitations when compared to private hosting such as monthly bandwidth usage (1 GB), disk space, cpu usage etc.  I am planning to embedd videos and audios (from other websites like youtube) to my already existing website. My question is if a client streams a embedded video/audio (hosted in another website) from my website any change in bandwidth occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OBVIOUSLY Not - because the data will come from where the video is hosted (in this case youtube) and not your server, with the exception of the tiny piece of additional HTML code that you have to embedd the video.